# Narrow moderator nomination

Tags: bug, status-review, election, nominations, mobile-safari

On Safari in portrait on my iPhone SE, the first moderator nomination is too narrow and is also pushed off the screen at the bottom. I have only seen this with the first [nomination on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election), but I’m sure it could happen on other sites under the right conditions:

[image]
...
[image]

By the way, the notification for the election doesn’t show in the app.

Comment: @BrianNickel Is the app notification also being reviewed?

Comment: If the notifications for elections aren't in the API, they can't be in the app. That's my guess for why you don't see them there.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce this.  On narrow screen widths (e.g., 320px), the tabs get forced below the "# candidates".  Since they are floating, their float now intersects with the tab bar and post body below and forces its content to narrow.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog I don't remember them ever working, so probably no.